# NSDateformatter stringFromDate returns wrong time string in iOS 10.3.1simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this method that converts date to string:

```
- (NSString*)getDateTimeBasedOnDeviceTimeFormat:(NSDate *)theDate{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSDate *dateSource;
    NSString *dateStr;

    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    if (theDate) {
        dateSource = theDate;
    } else {
        dateSource = [NSDate date];
    }

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; //tried local timezone
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateSource];

    return dateStr;
}
```

For iOS 10.3.1:

the returned value is **October 31, 2017 at 2:26 PM** (this is wrong)

For iOS 11:

the returned value is **October 31, 2017 at 10:26 AM** (this is correct)

Both the simulators have the same language and region set. English (US).

[image]

[image]

mac date time settings:

[image]
I have no idea why this conversion shows up wrong in iOS 10.3.1

Can someone point me in a right direction ?

Comment: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];` is redundant; this is what the formatter defaults to.

Comment: Why would you need to change the timezone anyways? Have you tried without the line where you do `setTimeZone:`?

Comment: I thought by setting timezone to systemTimeZOne, the app will adjust to the device timezone so date conversions for appointments won't messed up when users change their timezones. YEs, I tried without that line, the result is same. @TawaNicolas

Comment: Added screenshots of the timezone settings @rmaddy

Comment: I believe both the simulators share the same timezone setting from the mac.

Comment: I tried your code with the 10.3 simulator and got the correct result-- the local time at my location. Maybe try resetting the simulator?

Comment: it looks like the simulator issue, as the simulator time itself is showing wrong. The simulator shows the same wrong time even after resetting its contents. @TomHarrington

Comment: That's the real problem then-- the code can only show what the simulator claims the local time is.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Here is a radar that summarises the issue: [Versions of the iOS simulator for anything other than 11.0 and 11.1 use GMT instead of the macOS time zone.](http://www.openradar.me/34812060)

I have noticed this also, but on all non-11 iOS simulators in *Mac OS 10.13.1 only*.

Here's another example:

```
import Foundation
let formatterUTC = DateFormatter()
formatterUTC.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
formatterUTC.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
formatterUTC.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let d = formatterUTC.date(from:"2017-07-01T12:00:00Z")

let formatter24 = DateFormatter()
formatter24.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
formatter24.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let s = formatter24.string(from:d!) // ⚠️ "12:00" on iOS <= 10.3.1, Mac OS 10.13.1,
                                    //    "13:00" elsewhere! ⚠️
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty similar issue as to what I was experiencing when testing 10.3.1.  While debugging my dateFormatter, I noticed that the time zone on the simulator was always coming back as "GMT".  It didn't appear to be properly using my computer settings.

let timeZone = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() // produces "GMT" on iOS 10 and "PDT" on iOS 11

So I tested on physical device, everything was being displayed properly.  I'm chalking this one up to an Apple Simulator bug on 10.3.1 sims at least.  Hope this helps and I hope you have extra devices to test on!